# apply laravel localization 5.2 in the url

Tags: laravel

I have a yii site ti be transformed to **laravel** any help to apply the **laravel localization ** to the url such as

localhost/en/home
 localhost/ar/home

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is very simple to do in Laravel. First, you need to add a language prefix in your routes file (routes.php):

```
$languagesRegExp = implode('|', array_keys(Config::get('app.languages')));
Route::pattern('language', $languagesRegExp);
```

This will be our language prefix - it will only allow items from the languages[] specified in our app config file (config/app.php):

```
'languages' => [
    'ru' => ['prefix' => 'ru', 'title' => 'По-русски', 'locale' => 'ru_RU.utf8', 'google_code' => 'ru'],
    'en' => ['prefix' => 'en', 'title' => 'English', 'locale' => 'en_US.utf8', 'google_code' => 'en']
],
```

Then, routes that are going to have translated versions will look like:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => 'language'], function () {
    Route::get('/{language}', 'IndexController@index');
    Route::get('/{language}/about', 'StaticController@about');
}
```

Now we need a middleware because we want to change the application locale based on the prefix parameter. The middleware has a single method:

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    $urlSegments = explode('/', $request->path());
    View::share('language', $urlSegments[0]); // All views will have $language variable now
    App::setLocale($urlSegments[0]); // Laravel locale is set to $language now
    Cookie::queue(Cookie::make('siteLanguage', $urlSegments[0], 10800 * 7)); // We can also set a cookie, so that language is remembered

    return $next($request);
}
```

Pretty much that's it!

Comment: thank you it did work but now how can i add them to the view as links

Comment: Just parse through Config::get('app.languages') to generate alternative links. Display a link when the array key is not equal to current $language

Comment: so this is my code in view but the links of the nav bar does not chaaange

Comment: like this link <li><a href="{{ url('/about') }}">About</a></li>

Answer (score 0):

the answer of Denis Mysenko is amazingly working and in the view to add a dynamic urls and a language switcher here is the code

```
<div class="language_switcher">
                    <ul>
                         <li><a href="{{ url('/en') }}">en</a></li>
                         <li><a href="{{ url('/ar') }}">ar</a></li>
                    </ul>

                </div>
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button class="navbar-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar-main">
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                </div>

                <center>


                    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="navbar-main">                                

                        <div class="clearfix"></div>

                         <div class="clearfix"></div>


                       <ul class="nav navbar-nav  navbar-right">
                            <li><a href="{{ url('/' ,$language) }}">HOME</a></li>
                            <li><a href="{{ url('/ABOUT-US' , $language) }}">ABOUT US</a></li>
                            <li><a href="{{ url('/HOW-IT-WORKS' ,$language) }}">HOW IT WORKS</a></li>
                            <li><a href="{{ url('/CONTACT-US' ,$language) }}">CONTACT US</a></li>                          
                        </ul>



                    </div>
                </center>
```